# How to set up nested list view/expandable list view/multi-level list?

Tags: android, listview, nested, expandablelistview

this is my first question on this website.

I'm completely new to android this summer and have no experience with it at all. I'm trying to get my screen to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9RX7.jpg).

Obviously this is to be a basic planner, where the bars are expandable so I'd assume the expandablelistview would be the best for this task. Is that right? What would be the best way to go about this?

Sorry if this isn't in the right format for the website. I'm completely lost with android front end, even though I understand Java and jswing thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpandableListView is definitely a great choice according to your mockup image. You can get a tutorial here:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

You may want get familiar with basic ListView and Adapter first if you have never done this before.